# how to mock KStream in spring cloud stream for unit testing

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

How can I write a unit test for the below method:

```
 public KStream<String, Object> process(KStream<String, Object> kstream) {
        return kstream
            .filter((key, value) -> isFilterRequired(value))
            .mapValues(this::mapValues);
```

I am using Spring Cloud Stream framework, how could I mock KStream in order to invoke process method or how could I test this piece of code in Spring Kafka world.

Answer (score -1):

Create a method that returns Kafka Streams topology and then you will be able to test it using TopologyTestDriver. No need for mocking.

For more details see, [Testing Streams Code](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/test-streams.html) documentation from Confluent.